# dictionary operation using python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary.

```
dict = {'A':['a', 'b'], 'B':['c', 'b', 'a'], 'C':['d', 'c'], }
```

what is easy way to find out similar values from keys of dictionary?

```
output : 

A&B : 'a', 'b'
A&C : None
B&C : 'c'
```

How this can be achieved?

Comment: As your list contents are hashable, try e.g. `set(dict['A']).intersection(dict['B'])`. You shouldn't call your own object `dict`, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`set & other_set` operator or `set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) and [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> d = {'A':['a', 'b'], 'B':['c', 'b', 'a'], 'C':['d', 'c'], }
>>> for a, b in itertools.combinations(d, 2):
...     common = set(d[a]) & set(d[b])
...     print('{}&{}: {}'.format(a, b, common))
...
A&C: set()
A&B: {'b', 'a'}
C&B: {'c'}
```

Comment: and what if I want to get differences?

Comment: Use `set(..) - set(..)` or `set(..).difference(set(..))`. See [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference)

Comment: one more question. set(A) - set(B) doesnt give all the values from set A and B which are different. It gives only from set(A).

Comment: @sam, Ah, you want [`set.symmetric_difference` or `set ^ other_set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference).

Comment: @sam, Did you try `symmetric_difference` or `^` operator I mentioned in the previous comment? See http://ideone.com/aGENC1

Answer (score 9):

```
In [1]: dct = {'A':['a', 'b'], 'B':['c', 'b', 'a'], 'C':['d', 'c'], }

In [2]: set(dct['A']).intersection(dct['B'])
Out[2]: {'a', 'b'}

In [3]: set(dct['A']).intersection(dct['C'])
Out[3]: set()

In [4]: set(dct['B']).intersection(dct['C'])
Out[4]: {'c'}
```